# Recovering Outlook olk14 /15 email files

Tags: outlook, ms-office

My Office365 Uni-Account got deactivated and locally saved emails won't appear anymore inside Outlook (probably got corrupted during the switch to the newer Office365)
I've found a lot of olk15message, olk15msgsource and olk14 files. (MacOS)
Do these include the entire body or just information like "to", "from" etc.???

I'm not familiar with this script but it appears to do exactly what I need (https://github.com/glymphie/UBF8T346G9Parser).

Can someone who has used it before explain the steps I have to go through ?